# Sub navigation in IE9 is pushed above the navigation

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, position

I read some posts on this and for the life of me I cannot figure out my issue with ie9. On my navigation, when I hover over services, my sub nav is some how being pushed up above the navigation. I have tried making changes to some of the propeties and nothing has worked. The link to the site is www.colossalpoint.com also in ie 8 my site is completely off some one please help!

Answer (score 1):

to fix menu use position relative instead of static

```
<li class="MenuBarItemIE" style="position: relative;">
```

instead of

```
<li class="MenuBarItemIE" style="position: static;">
```

and better do it with stylesheet file, not inline

Comment: I have tried that and its not working when I set the position to relative, top 40px it doesnt even budge! this is the first time I have encountered this issue. Can you think of what else it might be?

Comment: Maybe it will help if I add the fact that I used dreamweaver spry horizontal drop down.